# extract specific rows in list

Tags: r, list

a and b are lists.

```
a<-list(matrix(1:36,9),matrix(7:38,8))
b<-list(matrix(c(1,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0),9),matrix(c(1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1),8))
```

The row number of objects in a and b are the same. I want extract rows form a where the value equals to 1 in b.

I use the following code:

```
Map(function(a,b) sapply(1:ncol(b), function(x) {a[which(b[,x]==1),]}), a,b)
```

but the result of the second object is not displayed in matrix:

```
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1   10   19   28
[2,]    2   11   20   29
[3,]    3   12   21   30
[4,]    4   13   22   31
[5,]    7   16   25   34
[6,]    9   18   27   36

[[1]][[2]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1   10   19   28
[2,]    5   14   23   32
[3,]    6   15   24   33
[4,]    7   16   25   34


[[2]]
      [,1]
 [1,]    7
 [2,]   10
 [3,]   14
 [4,]   15
 [5,]   18
 [6,]   22
 [7,]   23
 [8,]   26
 [9,]   30
[10,]   31
[11,]   34
[12,]   38
```

could you help me with that, thank you!

Comment: In the `b` `list`, the first element is a `matrix` with 2 columns.  So, what is the condition to have 1 value for that

Comment: @akrun so we need to output two matrix according to each column in the first element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can try

```
lapply(seq_along(a), function(i) 
    lapply(split(b[[i]], col(b[[i]])), 
        function(x) a[[i]][as.logical(x),]))
```

---

If we are using the OP's code, change `sapply` to `lapply` as `sapply` simplifies the `list` output to `matrix` or `vector` when the `length` of the elements are the same.

```
Map(function(a,b) lapply(1:ncol(b),
        function(x) {a[which(b[,x]==1),]}), a,b)
```

In case, we want to stick with `sapply`, use `simplify=FALSE` (as the default is TRUE)

```
Map(function(a,b) sapply(1:ncol(b),
        function(x) {a[which(b[,x]==1),]}, simplify=FALSE), a,b)
```

Comment: O, I made a mistake again in " lappy and sapply” ! Thank you so much, akrun!

Comment: Got it!! Thanks a lot!